# access Сумма прописью выходит ошибочно

Tags: ms-access

[image: подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка]

```css
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub Report_Activate()

Dim rns As Integer
Dim razr(4) As String
Dim sot(9) As String
Dim des(9) As String
Dim edin(19) As String
Dim ssum As Variant       'Currency 'Integer

Dim ssum1 As Variant
Dim nazv As String 'название прописью
Dim ost As Variant     'Integer
Dim ssum2 As Variant       'Currency 'String

Dim l As Variant    'Integer
Dim triad As Variant    'Integer
Dim x As Variant     'Integer
Dim j As Variant     'Integer
Dim i As Variant      'Integer
Dim m As Variant      'Integer
Dim xxx As Variant    'Integer

'Me!ВСЕГО = ssum
ssum = Me!Всего

razr(4) = " милрд."
razr(3) = " милн."
razr(2) = " тыс."
razr(1) = ""
'*DIME sot(9)
sot(1) = "сто "
sot(2) = "двести "
sot(3) = "триста "
sot(4) = "четыреста "
sot(5) = "пятьсот "
sot(6) = "шестьсот "
sot(7) = "семьсот "
sot(8) = "восемьсот "
sot(9) = "девятьсот "
'*DIME des(9)
des(1) = "десять "
des(2) = "двадцать "
des(3) = "тридцать "
des(4) = "сорок "
des(5) = "пятьдесят "
des(6) = "шестьдесят "
des(7) = "семьдесят "
des(8) = "восемьдесят "
des(9) = "девяносто "
'*DIME edin(19)
edin(1) = "один "
edin(2) = "два "
edin(3) = "три "
edin(4) = "четыре "
edin(5) = "пять "
edin(6) = "шесть "
edin(7) = "семь "
edin(8) = "восемь "
edin(9) = "девять "
edin(10) = "десять "
edin(11) = "одиннадцать "
edin(12) = "двенадцать "
edin(13) = "тринадцать"
edin(14) = "четырнадцать "
edin(15) = "пятнадцать "
edin(16) = "шестнадцать "
edin(17) = "семнадцать "
edin(18) = "восемнадцать "
edin(19) = "девятнадцать "

 If ssum = 0 Then
     nazv = "  ноль долларов 00 центов"
          
  Else
    ssum = ssum + 0#
    ssum1 = Int(ssum)      '2 435 000
        
    ssum2 = LTrim(CStr(Mid(ssum1, 1, 13)))
              
    l = Len(ssum2)         '7
    triad = Fix(l / 3)     '2
    ost = l - triad * 3     '1
    
    If ost > 0 Then
    
       triad = triad + 1
       ssum2 = String(3 - ost, "0") + ssum2
       
        
    End If
    
        If ost = -1 Then
                 ssum2 = "0" + ssum2
        End If
    
    x = 1
      
    nazv = ""
    i = triad           '=3
    Do While i > 0
         j = 1
         Do While j <= 3
             m = Val(Mid(ssum2, x, 1))
                       
                If m <> 0 Then
                    If j = 1 Then
                             nazv = nazv + sot(m)
                             x = x + 1
                          Else
                            If j = 3 Then
                                If i = 2 And m = 2 Then
                                             nazv = nazv + "две"
                                   Else
                                        If i = 2 And m = 1 Then
                                             nazv = nazv + "одна"
                                            Else
                                             nazv = nazv + edin(m)
                                        End If
                                   End If
                                    
                                    x = x + 1
                                Else
                                   If m = 1 Then
                                       m = Mid(ssum2, x, 2)
                                       nazv = nazv + edin(m)
                                       x = x + 2          '2
                                       j = j + 1
                                     Else
                                       nazv = nazv + des(m)
                                       x = x + 1
                                   End If
                                End If
                     End If
                Else
                x = x + 1
             End If
             j = j + 1
        Loop
    
         nazv = nazv + razr(i)
         i = i - 1
    
    Loop
    
       xxx = ssum - ssum1
       nazv = nazv + " долларов" + Mid(CStr(xxx), 3, 2) + " 00 центов"
       
  End If
Me!Пропись = nazv
End Sub

Private Sub Всего_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ЖДТ_Цена__BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub Надпись59_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Надпись60_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ОбластьДанных_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
Dim rns As Integer
Dim razr(4) As String
Dim sot(9) As String
Dim des(9) As String
Dim edin(19) As String
Dim ssum As Variant       'Currency 'Integer

Dim ssum1 As Variant
Dim nazv As String 'название прописью
Dim ost As Variant     'Integer
Dim ssum2 As Variant       'Currency 'String

Dim l As Variant    'Integer
Dim triad As Variant    'Integer
Dim x As Variant     'Integer
Dim j As Variant     'Integer
Dim i As Variant      'Integer
Dim m As Variant      'Integer
Dim xxx As Variant    'Integer

'Me!ВСЕГО = ssum

 
        ssum = Me!Всего
        

razr(4) = " милрд."
razr(3) = " милн."
razr(2) = " тыс."
razr(1) = ""
'*DIME sot(9)
sot(1) = "сто "
sot(2) = "двести "
sot(3) = "триста "
sot(4) = "четыреста "
sot(5) = "пятьсот "
sot(6) = "шестьсот "
sot(7) = "семьсот "
sot(8) = "восемьсот "
sot(9) = "девятьсот "
'*DIME des(9)
des(1) = "десять "
des(2) = "двадцать "
des(3) = "тридцать "
des(4) = "сорок "
des(5) = "пятьдесят "
des(6) = "шестьдесят "
des(7) = "семьдесят "
des(8) = "восемьдесят "
des(9) = "девяносто "
'*DIME edin(19)
edin(1) = "один "
edin(2) = "два "
edin(3) = "три "
edin(4) = "четыре "
edin(5) = "пять "
edin(6) = "шесть "
edin(7) = "семь "
edin(8) = "восемь "
edin(9) = "девять "
edin(10) = "десять "
edin(11) = "одиннадцать "
edin(12) = "двенадцать "
edin(13) = "тринадцать"
edin(14) = "четырнадцать "
edin(15) = "пятнадцать "
edin(16) = "шестнадцать "
edin(17) = "семнадцать "
edin(18) = "восемнадцать "
edin(19) = "девятнадцать "

 If ssum = 0 Then
     nazv = "  ноль долларов 00 центов"
          
  Else
    ssum = ssum + 0#
    ssum1 = Int(ssum)      '2 435 000
        
    ssum2 = LTrim(CStr(Mid(ssum1, 1, 13)))
              
    l = Len(ssum2)         '7
    triad = Fix(l / 3)     '2
    ost = l - triad * 3     '1
    
    If ost > 0 Then
    
       triad = triad + 1
       ssum2 = String(3 - ost, "0") + ssum2
       
        
    End If
    
        If ost = -1 Then
                 ssum2 = "0" + ssum2
        End If
    
    x = 1
      
    nazv = ""
    i = triad           '=3
    Do While i > 0
         j = 1
         Do While j <= 3
             m = Val(Mid(ssum2, x, 1))
                       
                If m <> 0 Then
                    If j = 1 Then
                             nazv = nazv + sot(m)
                             x = x + 1
                          Else
                            If j = 3 Then
                                If i = 2 And m = 2 Then
                                             nazv = nazv + "две"
                                   Else
                                        If i = 2 And m = 1 Then
                                             nazv = nazv + "одна"
                                            Else
                                             nazv = nazv + edin(m)
                                        End If
                                   End If
                                    
                                    x = x + 1
                                Else
                                   If m = 1 Then
                                       m = Mid(ssum2, x, 2)
                                       nazv = nazv + edin(m)
                                       x = x + 2          '2
                                       j = j + 1
                                     Else
                                       nazv = nazv + des(m)
                                       x = x + 1
                                   End If
                                End If
                     End If
                Else
                x = x + 1
             End If
             j = j + 1
        Loop
    
         nazv = nazv + razr(i)
         i = i - 1
    
    Loop
    
       xxx = ssum - ssum1
       nazv = nazv + " долларов" + Mid(CStr(xxx), 3, 2) + " 00 центов"
       
  End If
Me!Пропись = nazv


End Sub

Private Sub Пропись_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, получается значение для преобразования в операторе `ssum = Me!Всего`. Соответственно: а) какой тип у значения поля? б) почему используется переменная типа `Variant`? Для исправления: оба типа измените на точные (`Currency` подойдёт). И ведите вычисления в целых типах. а не Single/Double.

Comment: вы бы не могли выделить где надо исправить пожалуйста